# I have scenario , when the sales people have done some work then need to display progress using graphical process

Tags: visualforce

Suppose the work is divided into 3 steps, so that if the person completes the first task the progress bar (graphical) line should move, and if second task is done it should move automatically forward. Using a visualforce page.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Please show anything you have done towards this so far and explain which objects are being used to track the work - [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with a formula field. You can take a look at the last example on [Sample Image Link Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm) to get a feel for it. You can also provide you own images, of course.

Answer (score 0):

[See this example from Jitendra Zaa](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/creating-progress-bar-field-using-formula-without-any-coding/)

This example uses formula field to display progress.

Using VF page:

You can write a css to display progress.

```
<apex:page controller="ControllerExample">
  <head>
      <style>
        progress, progress[role] {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            border: none;
            background-size: auto;
            height: 15px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .skill-list {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        .skill {
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            position: relative;
        }

        .skill h3 {
            color: #fff;
            left: 1em;
            line-height: 1;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1em;
        }

        .skill ::-webkit-progress-value {
            -webkit-animation: bar-fill 2s;
            width: 0px;
        }

        .skill-1::-webkit-progress-value {
            background: #1797c0;
        }

        .skill-1::-webkit-progress-bar {
            background: #ccc;
        }

        .skill-2::-webkit-progress-value {
            background: #1797c0;
        }

        .skill-2::-webkit-progress-bar {
            background: #ccc;
        }

        .skill-3::-webkit-progress-value {
            background: #1797c0;
        }

        .skill-3::-webkit-progress-bar {
            background: #ccc;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes bar-fill {
            0% {
                width: 0;
            }
        }

        @keyframes bar-fill {
            0% {
                width: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
 </head>

  <progress class="skill-1" max="100" value="{!percentValue}"></progress>
  <!-- percentValue will be retrieved from Controller -->
</apex:page>
```